# Как реализовать собственную маршрутизация событий?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос теоретический. Представим, что есть у нас некое окно. В окне есть несколько слоев, сделанных на основе `UserControl`. Слои находятся один над другим, и полностью перекрывают друг друга. На каждом слое есть свои вьюхи. У вьюх, есть своя логика отображения и взаимодействия с пользователем. Т. е. обработка событий ввода находится во вьюхах. Это логично, т.к. именно они знают как правильно отображать информацию.

Внимание, вопрос: при пузырьковом и туннельном распространении событий, работать будет только самый "ближний" слой, все что под ним, не получит событий ввода. А надо чтоб получили.

Например, кликаем в некую точку, и на клик реагируют вьюхи, всех слоев, к которым принадлежит точка.

Я так понимаю, надо реализовывать некий диспетчер событий ввода. Но, может я чего то не знаю, и есть некий стандартный способ решения такой проблемы.

Comment: спасибо, что поправили. я к сожалению не нашел кнопочку редактировать...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, у `EventArgs` есть свойство `Handled`. Можно устанавливать его в `false`, и событие пойдет дальше.

Так же можно использовать `Messenger`, для передачи событий от одной `viewModel` к другой.

**Обновление**

Вкратце, есть два метода `Messenger.Register<TMessage>` и  `Messenger.Send<TMessage>`. Грубо говоря, для каждого события создается своя имплементация `TMessage`, например `NewMessage`. Любая ViewModel может подписатся на события этого типа через `Messenger.Register<NewMessage>` и так же может выстреливать этим событием, используя метод `Messenger.Send<NewMessage>`.

Comment: увы, Handled не подойдет, т.к. работает только в контексте стандартной маршрутизации событий. А можно поподробнее про Messenger ?

Comment: т.е. получается что необходимо делать обертку из пользовательских событий для событий ввода. вариант, но слишком сложный. проще написать некий роутер для стандартных событий ввода.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, почему невидимый слой должен получать ивенты. Раз он невидимый, то юзер не предполагает, что там есть что-то, что обладает логикой.

Если у вас, наоборот, верхний слой частично прозрачный, и контролы нижнего слоя видны, установите ему `null` бэкграундом, и сквозь прозрачные области клик и другие ивенты будут проходить в нижний слой.

Comment: тут дело в том, что слои разные и располагают вьюхи разными механизмами в разных координатных сетках. это диктуется предметной областью. в том числе есть и полупрозрачные элементы. если убрать бэкграунд, то событие пройдет на другой слой, это да. но тогда не отработает первый слой.

Comment: @Петр: Ну, вам нужно, чтобы на каждый клик реагировало _несколько_ элементов? Расскажите немного подробнее о вашей задаче.

Comment: да, примерно так. есть разные панели друг над другом. и гриды и канвасы.  вьюхи на них взаимопозиционируются, по принципам предметной области. есть полупрозрачные вьюхи. есть не прозрачные. вьюхи могут состоять практически из чего угодно, и иметь практически любую форму. Вот мы навели мышку на какую то точку, событие должны получить все вьюхи, на всех слоях, под этой точкой.т.е. получается не иерархическое распространение событий, как в WPF, а а параллельное.

Comment: @Петр: Окей, понял :) Сейчас попробую написать что-то под ваш случай.

Comment: ну, спасибо конечно, но вопрос немного в другом. вопрос в том, существуют ли стандартные средства C# или WPF для реализации такой маршрутизации событий. написать свой диспетчер не сложно, но не будет ли это велосипедом.

Comment: Стандартных я не знаю, но диспетчер вручную написать по идее несложно. Покрыть всё сверху невидимой панелью и ловить на ней, находить всё, что в этой точке через hittest и рассылать ивенты вручную.

Comment: ок. я понял. примерно так я и хотел сделать. а потом подумал, а не фигню ли я делаю ) спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Петр: Да в общем-то не за что. Подождите, пусть ещё WPF-спецы подтянутся, может, у кого-то буду идеи.